# how do we add row with dependent dropdown in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Hi i have stuck here where i am creating Addrow (+) if i click this button it adds a row how many times we click. These rows consist of two dropdown box where first one is coming from database value and second is dependent on first box . I am fully stuck.I am very new to laravel and i did not get any where how to do this.I have the Image how much far i have done.[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.addRow').on('click',function(){
    addRow();
    var i=1;
  });

  function addRow(){
    i++; 
    var tr = '<tr id="row'+i+'">'+
                    '<td>'+                     
                    '<select class="form-control input-lg dynamic" name="service_type[]" id="service_type" data-parsley-required="true" data-dependent="service_name">'+
                                '<option value="">Select Service Type</option>'+
                                @foreach ($services as $service )
                                  '<option value="{{ $service->service_type }}">{{ $service->service_type }}</option>'+
                                @endforeach
                              '</select>'+                        

                            '</td>'+
                  '<td>'+
                      '<select class="form-control input-lg dynamic" name="service_name[]" id="service_name" data-parsley-required="true">'+
                        '<option value="">Select Service name</option>'+
                      '</select>'+
                    '</td>'+
                  '<td><select class="form-control" name="service_sess[]" id="service_sess" data-parsley-required="true">'+
                                '<option value="">Select Sessions</option>'+
                                '<?php 

                                    for($i=0; $i<=20; $i++)
                                    {

                                        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                                    }
                                   ?>'+
                              '</select></td>'+
                  '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</td>'+
                '</tr>';
              $('tbody').append(tr);

  };
  i=1;
  $('tbody').on('click','.remove',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.dynamic').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
          var select = $(this).attr("id");
          var value = $(this).val();
          var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
          var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
          $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('StandardPackageController.fetch') }}",method:"POST",data:{select:select,value:value,_token:_token,dependent:dependent},
            success:function(result)
            {
              $('#'+dependent).html(result);
            }
          })
        }


    });

  });


</script>
```

These are my script for dynamic add row and fetch data dependency dropdown 
As you see in image first row is working as expected but second row and others are not.This is the problem.

Comment: Please share your Laravel controller and models

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Exactly i am doing like i have a page where row is added when i click on + button and also in that row i have dropdowns which are dependent .I will share the code .

Comment: See my updated one

Comment: I dont think you wanna set `var i=1;` everytime you click the add row button.

Comment: ok then how can i give new ids for each row